# Get all features of all layers clicked in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am using leaflet. Does anybody have a suggestion for a function that would return all of the features from all layers that a user clicks?

For example, I have a point layer, and a polygon layer. When a user clicks a point, I would like to display the attributes of the point and the polygon underneath that point. If the user only clicks the polygon, then it should only show attributes of the polygon.

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try the trick of looping through the feature layers?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Capture point clicked from event passed to `click` handler
2. Create bounding box for the point (`L.latLngBounds`)
3. Loop through each visible layer in `map._layers`
4. Find feature layers: if layer is a feature layer it has a `_layers` property; one layer for each feature
5. Loop through each feature in each feature layer, and get or create bounding box for each feature
6. Test for intersection of feature bounding box with the click bounding box created in step 1, and add to array
7. Display array contents to user to show all features behind point clicked.

(note: it is easier and more reliable if you keep track of your own features in a separate array. If you do this, you can skip steps 3 and 4.)

```js
// Create the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([39.5, -0.5], 5);

// Set up the OSM layer
var baseLayer1 = L.tileLayer(
  'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    name: "Base layer 1"
  }).addTo(map);

function clickHandler(e) {
  var clickBounds = L.latLngBounds(e.latlng, e.latlng);

  var intersectingFeatures = [];
  for (var l in map._layers) {
    var overlay = map._layers[l];
    if (overlay._layers) {
      for (var f in overlay._layers) {
        var feature = overlay._layers[f];
        var bounds;
        if (feature.getBounds) bounds = feature.getBounds();
        else if (feature._latlng) {
          bounds = L.latLngBounds(feature._latlng, feature._latlng);
        }
        if (bounds && clickBounds.intersects(bounds)) {
          intersectingFeatures.push(feature);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // if at least one feature found, show it
  if (intersectingFeatures.length) {
    var html = "Found features: " + intersectingFeatures.length + "<br/>" + intersectingFeatures.map(function(o) {
      return o.properties.type
    }).join('<br/>');

    map.openPopup(html, e.latlng, {
      offset: L.point(0, -24)
    });
  }
}

map.on("click", clickHandler);

// add some markers
function createMarker(lat, lng) {
  var marker = L.marker([lat, lng]);
  marker.on("click", clickHandler);
  marker.properties = {
    type: "point"
  }; // add some dummy properties; usually would be geojson
  return marker;
}
var markers = [createMarker(36.9, -2.45), createMarker(36.9, -2.659), createMarker(36.83711, -2.464459)];

// create group to hold markers, it will be added as an overlay
var overlay = L.featureGroup(markers).addTo(map);

// show features
map.fitBounds(overlay.getBounds(), {
  maxZoom: 11
});

// create another layer for shapes or whatever
var circle = L.circle([36.9, -2.45], 2250, {
  color: 'red',
  fillColor: '#f03',
  fillOpacity: 0.5
});
circle.on('click', clickHandler);
circle.properties = {
  type: "circle"
};
var overlay2 = L.featureGroup([circle]).addTo(map);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

JS Fiddle in case you want to, you know, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xn8opdjq/

Comment: btw, this is also a very useful trick for resolving ambiguity between features (if multiple matches instead of one) when you are not using marker cluster plugin, etc.

Comment: OK, so the solution is not perfect. While the JSfiddle scenario works, the polygon (cirlce) is quite small. this procedure does not measure 'clicks in polygon', rather it measures 'click in the square bounding box of a polygon'. It would probably work with a point in polygon function.

Comment: Yes you are correct this is probably not ideal as is for non-square geometries. I use this technique for doing my own custom search (type in search bar some data, then I grep for records in visible layers whose properties match the search, and then show a "feature results" list). However if you augment my solution with what Toni BCN posted (point in polygon plugin) you can verify whether the point is in one of the polygons intersected by bounding box - this would still have benefit of reducing problem space (fewer polygons to test). After step 6, test for point in polygon (or whatever shape).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @nothingisnecessary response, see [pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) (point in polygon) for leaflet